# Why to_notebook_iframe (ydata-profiling) does not render the report on SageMaker notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas-profiling, amazon-sagemaker-studio, data-profiling

I am facing an issue to show the ydata-profiling report in the notebook using SageMaker studio. Everything looks fine to create the report, but the report render does not show up at the end and the cell stuck in this part. If I try the `to_widgets`, it stucks in 0% and stucks, while printing `profile` has the same behaviour as `to_notebook_iframe` (render 100% but does not show up and stucks). Besides, `to_file` works fine and I can open the generated file on notebook. I did not figure out why the report is not showing up at the end and freezing the cell.

- versions

  - python: 3.10
  - pandas: 2.1.3
  - ydata-profiling: 4.6.4

[image]